# Save related(one to one) Model in YII having reference of parent

Tags: yii

I'm having trouble on inserting a new record having a parent .

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_a".
 * @property integer $id
....
 */

class A extends CACtiveRecord{


}
?>


<?php
/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_b".
 * @property integer $id
....
* The followings are the available model relations:
* @property A $a
 */

class B extends CACtiveRecord{
//codes...

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'a' => array(self::BELONGS_TO , 'A', 'id'),
    );
}   

}

?>
```

This is the structure of my model classes.
here the 'id' of tbl_b is set as the primary key and also is the foreign key referencing tbl_a. 'id' of tbl_a is its primary key.

My issue here is, when i tried to save model object of B ($b->save()), after setting all the attributes excluding 'id' (But the property 'a' of the object[$b] is set with an active record of model 'A' say having primary key 10), an exception is thrown on inserting the record because of no 'id' is set to it. But when I tried the same after setting the 'id' of the model object, it inserted correctly.
Why we need to set the foreign key attribute of the child model even the related property is set? 
Is there any solution for this. So that the foreign key reference id is taken automaticaly from the related model obj?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is will be automatically generated only if your database support it. Yii will not create id by himself. If you are using MySQL as your RDMS, primary key should be marked as auto_increment. But in your situation, you are using foreign key as your primary key. So the most preferable way for you is to overload `beforeSave` method of `B` model and fetch `a::id` as `b::id`:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if (parent::beforeSave())
    {
        $this->id = $this->a->id;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```